# React native X.match not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Code:

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'

export default class mapTestProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MapView>
         style = {styles.map}
         showsUserLocation = {false}
         followUserLocation = {false}
         zoomEnabled = {true}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
      height: 400,
      marginTop: 80
   },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('mapTestProject', () => mapTestProject);
```

I am trying to create a sample map project.It gives "x.match not a function" error.Please help me on fixing this issue.any help will be appreicated.thanks in advance

[image]"

Comment: I don't see any x.match in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

React Components name must begin with `upper case letter` since all lower case are reserved for the HTML tags like `div, p, span, li etc`

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'

export default class MapTestProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MapView>
         style = {styles.map}
         showsUserLocation = {false}
         followUserLocation = {false}
         zoomEnabled = {true}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
      height: 400,
      marginTop: 80
   },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('mapTestProject', () => MapTestProject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with the latest version of react-native-maps v0.14.0
Temporally using v0.13.1 solved the problem:

```
npm install react-native-maps@0.13.1 --save
react-native link
```